# Adjective word or phrase to mean "We built it for ourselves"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, adjectives, compound-adjectives

I'm having a bit of a block here. I'm trying to describe a piece of machinery. It doesn't exist anywhere else. We didn't build it, but we designed it to maximize our productivity. It only exists in our factories. How can I describe that machinery? I thought of *proprietary machinery* but it's much more than just proprietary. How can I refer to this concept?

Comment: 'Unique' carries the sense 'all our own'. But haven't you / the constructors patented it?

Comment: Consider ***home-made*** and ***makeshift***, among others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: *Custom-built to our specifications*, or *we had the machines made to spec*.